# ModuleNotFoundError in PyCharm for matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I was looking for matpoltlib.pylot package on Pycharm . I couldn't found this package and i installed matplotlib instead.

I installed it from file>setting>project interpreter.

On importing the package:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get error as follow:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I expected to see a normal distribution plot.

Comment: Post the ouput of 'pip list' typed in terminal of Pycharm

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot` is a submodule of `matplotlib`. Meaning if you successfully installed matplotlib, pyplot is included. The error suggests that you haven't successfully installed matplotlib.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags

Comment: Please check that run configurations in `Run - Edit Configurations` use the same interpreter as specified in `File - Settings - Project Interpreter`